# Java regex pattern too long?

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex which is a bit longer than usual. I try to capture some values in a text document.

```
\\n*.*(k\\s=\\s\\d)(.|\\n)*?estimate\\s.*\\n*\\s*((\\d+|<)\\.\\d+)\\s*((\\d+|<)\\.\\d+)\\s*((\\d+|<)\\.\\d+)\\s*((\\d+|<)\\.\\d+)\\s*((\\d+|<)\\.\\d+)\\s*((\\d+|<)\\.\\d+)\\s+
```

It works perfectly fine on regexr.com [link](http://regexr.com/3gmet)

but in Java only this part works

```
\\n*.*(k\\s=\\s\\d)(.|\\n)*?estimat
```

as soon as I add the missing 'e' it stops working.

For now I am ignoring that some groups are filled wrongly.

What goes wrong?

Comment: Sounds weird, can you post a snippet of Java code that reproduces it?

Comment: Watch input string.

Comment: In your case I would totally split up the text first with a regex, then I would analyze the values you are interested in with a second regex or more. Doing everything with a single regex is a pain in the a$$

Comment: Never use `(.|\\n)*?`. Replace with `(?s:.*?)`. In regexr, the `.*?` that should match across lines should be replaced with `[^]*?` (since that site uses JS regex flavor).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. That made it work!

Comment: @SebastianBauer Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(.|\\n)*?` makes the regex engine perform too many redundant backtracking steps. You need to replace all such parts in your pattern with `(?s:.*?)`, a modifier group that matches any 0+ chars including line break chars. Since there is no alternation, there is no redundant backtracking here.

Note that in JavaScript (as you are testing the pattern at regexr.com that only supports JavaScript regex flavor), the `(.|\n)*?` should be replaced with `[^]*?` or `[\s\S]*?` as its regex engine does not support inline modifiers at all.